# How to get screen dimensions in React Native

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer, react-navigation-drawer

I'm trying to create a full-width navigation drawer using React Native. So far I wrote this code:

```js
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';

const {customWidth} = Dimensions.get('window').width; //<-- DOES NOT WORK

const AppDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Home: {screen: HomeScreen},
    Details: {screen: DetailScreen},
  },
  {
    contentOptions: {activeTintColor: 'orange'},
    contentComponent: customerDrawerComponent,
    drawerWidth: customWidth,
    drawerPosition: 'right',
  },
);
```

Despite setting a custom width, the drawer opens only half-way through screen's width, not fully. Can you please help me understand the issue.

**UPADTE**: I figured out that `Dimensions.get('window')` and `Dimensions.get('screen')` return `undefined`. But why?

Comment: try const customWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width; instead and console.log(customWidht) - it should show it to you

Comment: import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';

    const width = Dimensions.get('window').width;
    const height = Dimensions.get('window').height;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the bug myself. Actually those extra `{` and `}` were the issues. I should have written:

```js
const customWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
```

As simple as that.